# Convert double to float in Java

Tags: java, double, floating

I am facing an issue related to converting `double` to `float`. Actually, I store a float type, `23423424666767`, in a database, but when we get data from the database in the below code, `getInfoValueNumeric()`, it's of `double` type. The value we get is in the `2.3423424666767E13` form.

So how do we get a `float` format data like `23423424666767`?

`2.3423424666767E13 to 23423424666767`

```
public void setInfoValueNumeric(java.lang.Double value) {
    setValue(4, value);
}


@javax.persistence.Column(name = "InfoValueNumeric", precision = 53)
public java.lang.Double getInfoValueNumeric() {
    return (java.lang.Double) getValue(4);
}
```

Comment: just cast it. double d = 3.0;
float f = (float) d;

Comment: The numbers look the same, just different representations of the same value.

Comment: Its not working for me

Comment: if its the formatting you wish to archieve use the NumberFormat libary. If you want to shorten your number. Like: 10000->100 you could use math.round()

Comment: `float` doesn't have enough precision for such numbers like 23423424666767. It can only be precise to ~7 decimal digits

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Just cast your double to a float.

```
double d = getInfoValueNumeric();
float f = (float)d;
```

Also notice that the primitive types can NOT store an infinite set of numbers:

```
float range: from 1.40129846432481707e-45 to 3.40282346638528860e+38
double range: from 1.7e–308 to 1.7e+308
```

Comment: @JimmyKane make sure you use the primitive types "float" and "double" and not the object types "Float", "Double".

Comment: Hey, Tom is this an expensive operation. Can you explain what Java is doing under the hood?

Comment: @SamOrozco here are basically two things that happen:
1. the double value is autoBoxed to its object type. It is basically a new instance of Double that hold the primitive double value.
2. As the objectTypes Double and Float are both derived from Number they can be converted into each other.

Comment: Now to come back to your question, as we narrow down our type from Double to Float instead of going broader eg. Double to Object. Java has to check for potential ClassCastExceptions at runtime. But I can't really say how much of an Overhead that produces. As for the calculation itself it is nothing more than creating Object instances (autoboxing) and retrieving the primitive Value (autoUnboxing).

I know my answer is vague, but I hope it helps none the less. If you are really interested check out Topics related to auto-(un)boxing here at Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 27):

I suggest you to retrieve the value stored into the Database as BigDecimal type:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("2.3423424666767E13");

int myInt = number.intValue();
double myDouble = number.doubleValue();

// your purpose
float myFloat = number.floatValue();
```

BigDecimal provide you a lot of functionalities.

Comment: If anyone is passing a value that is not a String, it's recommended to use _BigDecimal.valueOf()_ instead of _new BigDecimal()_. See [https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S2111](https://dev.eclipse.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S2111)

Comment: That old link is dead. Here is another:

https://sonar.spring.io/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2111

Answer (score 27):

Convert `Double` to `Float`

```
public static Float convertToFloat(Double doubleValue) {
    return doubleValue == null ? null : doubleValue.floatValue();
}
```

Convert `double` to `Float`

```
public static Float convertToFloat(double doubleValue) {
    return (float) doubleValue;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

This is a nice way to do it:

```
Double d = 0.5;
float f = d.floatValue();
```

if you have d as a primitive type just add one line:

```
double d = 0.5;
Double D = Double.valueOf(d);
float f = D.floatValue();
```

Comment: Very elegant. I feel safer using this method than just casting --even if it is false security.

Answer (score 5):

Converting from double to float will be a narrowing conversion. From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html):

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the
>   overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and
>   range.
>
> A narrowing primitive conversion from double to float is governed by
>   the IEEE 754 rounding rules (§4.2.4). This conversion can lose
>   precision, but also lose range, resulting in a float zero from a
>   nonzero double and a float infinity from a finite double. A double NaN
>   is converted to a float NaN and a double infinity is converted to the
>   same-signed float infinity.

So it is not a good idea. If you still want it you can do it like:

```
double d = 3.0;
float f = (float) d;
```

Answer (score 3):

> To answer your query on "How to convert 2.3423424666767E13 to
>   23423424666767"

You can use a [decimal formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for formatting decimal numbers.

```
     double d = 2.3423424666767E13;
     DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
     System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));
```

Output : 23423424666767

Comment: This does not convert a double value to float... `format` method return a String object.

Comment: well afterwards the String can be parsed without much effort

Comment: You can always convert a string value to float by 'Float.parseFloat(decimalFormat.format(d))' . Although it still represent the value with scientific representation as **2.34234241E13** .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your value cannot be stored accurately in single precision floating point type. Proof:

```
public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Float a = Float.valueOf("23423424666767");
        System.out.printf("%f\n", a); //23423424135168,000000
        System.out.println(a);        //2.34234241E13
    }
}
```

Another thing is: you don't get "2.3423424666767E13", it's just the visual representation of the number stored in memory. "How you print out" and "what is in memory" are two distinct things. Example above shows you how to print the number as float, which avoids scientific notation you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the fact that the value in the database is a float does not mean that it also fits in a Java `float`. Float is short for *floating point*, and floating point types of various precisions exist. Java types `float` and `double` are both floating point types of different precision. In a database both are called `FLOAT`. Since `double` has a higher precision than `float`, it probably is a better idea *not* to cast your value to a `float`, because you might lose precision.

You might also use `BigDecimal`, which represent an arbitrary-precision number.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataType casting.  For example:

```
// converting from double to float:
double someValue;
// cast someValue to float!
float newValue = (float)someValue;
```

Cheers!

Note:

Integers are whole numbers, e.g. 10, 400, or -5.

Floating point numbers (floats) have decimal points and decimal places, for example 12.5, and 56.7786543.

Doubles are a specific type of floating point number that have greater precision than standard floating point numbers (meaning that they are accurate to a greater number of decimal places).

Answer (score -1):

Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(your_number)