# How to set double value as rating in rating bar?

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

How to set double value in rating bar, i have search there is no method which works on a double value. I also no there is no chance to convert double to float.

Comment: double to float https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837783/convert-double-to-float-in-java

Comment: @Rohit5k2 I tried your suggestion but not works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it 
 String ratedValue = String.valueOf(ratingBar.getRating());

```
            rateMessage.setText("Rating : " + ratedValue + "/5");
```

Comment: I used this approach but i want to show perfect ratings.